# Functions and variable declaration in C++

Tags: c++, function, variables

In the following code, why must `int nInteger` be declared inside `int readNumber()`'s body, but `int nAnswer` must be declared inside the () portion of `void writeAnswer()`? Declaring `int nInteger` inside the () or declaring `int nAnswer` inside the function body causes the IDE to complain about too few arguments for said function. Why does this happen?

I'm using Code::Blocks and the included MinGW on a Windows 7.

```
#include <iostream>

int readNumber()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    int nInteger;
    cin >> nInteger;
    return nInteger;
}

void writeAnswer(int nAnswer)
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "The sum is: " << nAnswer << endl;
}

int main()
{

    int x;
    int y;
    x = readNumber();
    y = readNumber();

    writeAnswer(x+y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you read some introductory material on functions? If not, please do so.

Comment: You seem to not understand the difference between a local variable and a passed variable

Comment: I guess you have to read [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/3959454)

Comment: If you you declare variable as a parameter of function, this means the value of this variable come from other function.

Comment: Read up on **function arguments**.

Comment: These questions demands so elaborate explanation. Maybe you should try to brush up your basics.

Comment: Also no need to write `using namespace std;` in every function. You can write it one time after `#include <iostream>`

Comment: @user4757345 actually if you are going to use `using namespace standard` putting it in the function scope is more correct since you don't pollute the global namespace with all of the standard symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basicly the int readNumber() function does not require any argument to be passed. You declare a local variable so the function knows where to assign the value you type in. You declare variable `int nInteger` and then in the very next line you assign a value to it by calling `cin >> nInteger`. If there was no variable declared then your program wouldn't know where to store the value that you type in.

You can think of it as of a basket for apples. You have one basket but no apples in it, then someone gives you 2 apples that you put into the basket. In the end the `return` statement work like you give the basket to someone else.

Function `void writeAnswer` on the other hand requires an argument to be passed. As you can see there in local variable declared. What it does is to simply display `"The sum is: PASSED_ARGUMENT"`. So basicly if you call your writeAnswer function with number 6 like `writeAnswer(6)` it will write `"The sum is: 6"`.

Comment: Thank you, @Dashovsky. To be honest, I'm still confused about why I must declare a variable in the function body of an `int` type function and inside the () of a `vois` type function. But now I have an ideia of what I should study further. Again, thank you for answering!